# ldap errors-LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9

Tags: ldap

we have  configured ldap settings in tomcat.its working fine all these days.but suddenly getting below ldap errors.what is the meaning of below errors.

this is ldap configuration set in tomcat config file.

```
Jul 19, 2016 11:14:04 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Realm} Setting property 'debug' to '99' did not find a matching property.
    Jul 19, 2016 11:14:04 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Realm} Setting property 'curUserPattern' to '%s@corp' did not find a matching property.
    Jul 19, 2016 11:14:04 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Realm} Setting property 'resourceName' to 'add_web_realm' did not find a matching property.
    Jul 19, 2016 11:14:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
    SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/add-web]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)


    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[JNDIRealm]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5350)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Exception opening directory server connection
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.startInternal(JNDIRealm.java:2191)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 12 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 775, v1db1^@]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3087)
```

Comment: $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml  changed ?    LDAP error code 49 indicates "Invalid credentials" which means the password you sent to the LDAP server was not correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your issue lies in the LDAP error code:

> [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment:
>   AcceptSecurityContext error, **data 775**, v1db1^@]

The `data 775` is the important part. That hex code translates to a decimal system error code of 1909, which is a windows system error code. That is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681386(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ERROR_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT
>
> ```
> 1909 (0x775)
>
> The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.
> ```

So it would appear that an account you're trying to use is locked.

Comment: added the ldap configuration in the main question;during server restart itself we are seeing above error.may i know where are we giving account settings in configuration? i didnt see there.

Comment: I'm not sure I see where you added the config...shouldn't there be some XML or something? You could probably search your config settings file for 'ldap://' or 'dc=' or something similar to find where it is.